# Security issue of SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL Server DB in a folder, which is attached to SQLEXPRESS instance of my SQL Server.  I wonder what is the security of this DB.  I tried to copy the file, and it can easily be copied to any folder, anybody can attach it to SQL and can see what data it contains.

Please advise how it can be protected from being copied and attached by unauthorized persons?

Thanks

Comment: File system permissions?

Comment: TDE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb934049.aspx

Comment: [TDE is only supported in Enterprise Edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#Enterprise_security), but the OP is using Express Edition, so he can't use TDE.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is properly secured, unauthorized persons shouldn't be able to see the file system.
You can't copy what you can't see.

Of course, your users should be able to connect to the database [by using the server name, database name and some kind of authentication](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

**And that's the only kind of access to that server that your users are supposed to have.**

Only administrators should be able to:

- access the file system of the server so that they can even see the actual database file
- have physical access to the actual hardware server *(so no one else is able to plug in an USB drive, for example)*